# How to vertically center inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, display

These two icons should be printed in the same line and vertically aligned with the container box

HTML:

```
<div id="field-filter-TIPO" class="container"><svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" class="octicon octicon-x-circle-fill first" viewBox="0 0 12 12" width="12" height="12" fill="currentColor">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.757 10.243a6 6 0 118.486-8.486 6 6 0 01-8.486 8.486zM6 4.763l-2-2L2.763 4l2 2-2 2L4 9.237l2-2 2 2L9.237 8l-2-2 2-2L8 2.763l-2 2z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div title="ColumnFilter" kind="ColumnFilter" id="columnfilter--fetching" name="Fetching" class="second"><button><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" font-size="24" class="css-1cx02qk" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <desc></desc>
        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
        <path d="M5.5 5h13a1 1 0 0 1 .5 1.5l-5 5.5l0 7l-4 -3l0 -4l-5 -5.5a1 1 0 0 1 .5 -1.5"></path>
      </svg></button></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: block;
}

.first {
    display: inline-block;
  user-select: none; 
  overflow: visible;
}

.second {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However the left icon is printed as it is like pushed to the bottom

[image]

How can I vertically center both elements like the container defines a `display: flex` with `align-items: center`?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/asant93/dho2u8r7/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: `display: flex; align-items: center;` Apply these on the container with id `field-filter-TIPO` and you should be good.

Comment: @Santosh I can't use flex because I need to set a negative right margin for the icon on the left

Comment: @CBroe `vertical-align: middle;` doesn't help

Comment: @AntonioSantoro how about applying `margin-bottom: 5px;` for `.first` selector?

Comment: _"doesn't help"_ - yes, it does - as soon as you apply it to _both_ elements, to override the default value `baseline`.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, why it won't align the first element if the second one defines `baseline`?